# Does artifactory support mutually exclusive properties or can it automatically "prune" properties from artifacts?

Tags: artifactory

What I would like to do is something like this:

- build and push app/package to artifactory
- deploy that artifact (not using jfrog pipelines)
- after deployment add metadata (a custom Property set) to the artifact that was deployed that includes info like when it was deployed, where it was deployed if the deployment failed or succeeded, and something like "LatestDeploymentAttempt:true|false")
- build a script/dashboard to list all the deployed artifacts and the metadata

All of that is doable but I have a question about how I can implement a `LatestDeploymentAttempt:true` property

What I want is a behavior where I can apply a property to an artifact and immediately that same property is removed from all other versions of that artifact. So I can add a property like LatestDeploymentAttempt: true to an artifact version and jfrog automatically removes LatestDeploymentAttempt property from all other versions of that package- this would make listing the deployed versions easier if I can filter on a single property

Is this possible?

If there is a way to say "remove this property from all versions" with the REST API I could manually remove it before adding it to the artifact that was deployed but it would be nice if jfrog has some kind of built-in way of doing this.

Comment: Do the versions share a pattern in Artifactory? If so, you can delete properties using JFrog CLI which accepts regexp/wildcard.
I think a better approach would be publishing a build info after each deployment. Artifacts deployed with the build will have the build properties which you can relay upon when retrieving the latest.

Comment: can I search by pattern and property? Could I query for all artifacts matching a pattern with a specific property?

Comment: sure, the options of the command are for filtering and the arguments are the properties set:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SettingPropertiesonFiles

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by implementing a [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/User+Plugins) using the `beforePropertyCreate` or `afterPropertyCreate` event callback.
The plugin can use the [Artifactory public API](https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html) for searching the artifacts which are already tagged with this property using [AQL](https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/org/artifactory/search/Searches.html#aql(java.lang.String,org.artifactory.search.aql.AqlResultHandler)) (Artifctory Query Language) or [by property](https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/org/artifactory/search/Searches.html#itemsByProperties(com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap,java.lang.String...)).
You can find examples of Artifactory user plugins in the JFrog GitHub user plugins [repository](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins).

Here is a basic example of such a plugin:

```
import org.artifactory.repo.RepoPath
import org.artifactory.search.aql.AqlResult
import org.artifactory.repo.RepoPathFactory
import java.util.Map

storage {
    beforePropertyCreate { item, name, values ->
        if (name == 'LatestDeploymentAttempt') {
            String aqlQuery = 'items.find({"$and" : [{"repo" : "my-repo-local"}, {"@LatestDeploymentAttempt" : {"$eq" : "true"}}]})'
            searches.aql(aqlQuery) { AqlResult result ->
                result.each { Map artifact ->
                    String itemPath = artifact.path + "/" + artifact.name
                    RepoPath repoPath = RepoPathFactory.create(artifact.repo, itemPath)
                    repositories.deleteProperty(repoPath, 'LatestDeploymentAttempt')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: created new tag. custom plugins are not supported by jfrog cloud: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-add-user-plugins-to-artifactory-cloud/